# how to change library method signature C#

Tags: c#, c#-7.0

I am consuming some external library that have one method which except parameter as Func type.

```
    class LibClass
    {
        public void libMethod(Func<int, int, int> add)
        {
            add(5, 5);
        }

    }
```

In my Console app i am consuming  like

```
class Program
    {
        public static  int MyMethod(int a, int b) // want to pass third parameter 
        {
            return 0;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            LibClass obj = new LibClass();
            obj.libMethod(Program.MyMethod); 
            Console.Read();

        }
    }
```

I want to pass some additional parameter to MyMethod(), but i am not able to pass it. so how can change library  method signature?
or how i can pass additional parameter to MyMethod()?

Comment: you cant change the signature of the function in the library. Why can't you change the signature of `MyMethod`?

Comment: BTW the `libMethod` function does not require 3 parameters - the third `int` defines the return type

Answer (score 3):

You would have to recompile the library from source in order to change its methods, but I think this might be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You shouldn't need to change the signature to pass another parameter to your method. Example:

```
int DoSomeMath(int a, int b, int x)
{
    return (a + b) * x;
}
```

If you wanted to have `libMethod` call `DoSomeMath` with more parameters, you can just wrap it in a lambda and add your own:

```
void Main()
{
    LibClass obj = new LibClass();
    obj.libMethod((a, b) => DoSomeMath(a, b, 42));
    Console.Read();
}
```

The lambda will receive `a` and `b` from `libMethod`, pass those along with `42` to `DoSomeMath`, and return the return value of `DoSomeMath` back to `libMethod`.